# export fusioncharts to ppt

Tags: javascript, asp.net, fusioncharts

Here i am trying to export the fusioncharts to ppt on button click.First i am converting fusioncharts to images and then export them to ppt.As i need to generate ppt after the images are saved i am using a **stopwatch** function in javascript to calculate the time taken to convert the fusioncharts to image.This is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var initiateExport = false;
            var _sw = new StopWatch();
            var time;
            function exportReport() {
                exportCharts();
                                return false;
                }
            function exportCharts() {
                _sw.start();
            var exportFormat = 'JPG';
            initiateExport = true;
            for (var chartRef in FusionCharts.items) {
                if (FusionCharts.items[chartRef].exportChart) {
                    document.getElementById("linkToExportedFile").innerHTML = "Exporting...";
                    FusionCharts.items[chartRef].exportChart({ "exportFormat": exportFormat });

                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("linkToExportedFile").innerHTML = "Please wait till the chart completes rendering...";
                }
            }
        }
        function FC_Exported(statusObj) {
           _sw.stop();
            time = _sw.duration();
            setTimeout(' document.getElementById("MainContent_Button1").click();', time);

        }
    </script>
```

In the above code the  **document.getElementById("MainContent_Button1").click();** function generates the ppt.My problem is as i have 3 fusioncharts the function FC_Exported is executed 3 times.So i am getting a prompt for ppt 3 times.**I want it to happen only 1 time**.Also i think the placement of the ppt code cannot be changed because i am using **time** parameter.Can someone please guide me? Awaiting your response.Thank you.

**NOTE: The stop functionality of the timer cannot be placed anywhere else because i want the total time taken to generate and save the image.**

Answer (score 0):

You may try using [oomfo](http://oomfo.com/) from FusionCharts. It is meant for the PowerPoint '03 and upper versions.

Comment: Hi..I was looking more for a solution involving javascript.But anyhow we finally managed to solve the problem using c# version of the code.Anyhow thanx for your response.

Answer (score 0):

recently i used fusioncharts to export as ppt. The process is very simple which is as follows:

```
- Capture image from the client side 
- Save Image at server side
- Use Apache POI to create a slideshow 
- Add stored image in slide as :

          // get server context
             ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();  

         // get image stored file path       
             String []imagefilename=filename.split("/ExportedImages");

         // get image filename 
             String filename = context.getRealPath("/ExportedImages"+imagefilename[1]); 


         // Create Slide
         Slide slide1 = slideShow.createSlide();
          try {
              int idx=slideShow.addPicture(new File(filename), org.apache.poi.hslf.model.Picture.JPEG);

              org.apache.poi.hslf.model.Picture pict = new org.apache.poi.hslf.model.Picture(idx);

              //set image position in the slide
              pict.setAnchor(new java.awt.Rectangle(100, 100, 300, 200));

              slide1.addShape(pict);


        } catch (IOException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


      - Then Download file
```